# What does energy scale refer to in QED?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

We hear the phrase 'the coupling constant runs with the energy scale'. In practical terms what does this mean?
If 2 high energy particles collide and create a bunch of particles i assume we take the energy of the incoming particles as the energy scale. Then we use this to determine a coupling constant. Then we do the qed calculations which will give us a result to a certain accuracy.

If we input the 'energy scale' as even higher presumably we could get a more accurate result for the same process or not?

And would it be that the higher the energy scale the more difficult the calculations as the coupling constant will be less small?

Have i got this right?

Comment: Surely at a higher energies QED becomes *less* accurate?

Comment: No because higher energy corresponds to shorter space and time. So it should probe smaller distances. Hence setting the energy scale high for a low energy collision should result in more accuracy. I.e. treating a low energy collision as a high energy scale experiment

Comment: Of course this is in an ideal world where only photons and electrons exist

Comment: If the theory you're using to make predictions is QED, you are going to reach an energy scale at which QED fails and you will need something new, that's what I'm saying.